# JQuery Image OnClick Add Border

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I need some JQuery code so that I can add a CSS border to an image when I click on it.

```
<img src="myimage" onclick="AddBorder();" />
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you're using jQuery, I'd recommend removing the inline onclick handler, as that's the less desirable way to bind to the event:

```
<img src="http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png" />
```

And then just setup a simple event binder:

```
$(function () {
  $("img").click(function() {
    $(this).css('border', "solid 2px red");  
  });
});
```

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fordlover49/6z4tH/3/)

Answer (score 1):

In that onClick, instead of AddBorder();, place:

```
$(this).css("border","1px solid black");
```

Answer (score -1):

Er... what have you tried so far?

```
function AddBorder() { $(this).css('border','1px solid red'); }
```

Comment: Please don't mark -1 unless you also add a comment explaining why